# Spring SAML: Could not find artifacts while using as maven dependency with version 1.0.4.RELEASE

Tags: maven-dependency, spring-security-saml2

I am trying to use `spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.4.RELEASE` as maven dependency for my project and encounter two issues when `mvn install`:

1. Failure `"Could not find artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4 ... "`. I have not found 1.4 version of xml-apis dependency neither in Maven repository nor in repositories listed in [build.gradle](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/rb1.0.4.RELEASE/build.gradle) file. As a workaround I am forced to add explicit dependency with slightly different version to my project:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
       <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.01</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Failure: `"Could not find artifact org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.6.6 ..." and "Could not find artifact ca.juliusdavies:not-yet-commons-ssl:jar:0.3.17 ..."`. As a workaround I am forced to add explicit maven repositories where I was able to find the artifacts to my project:

   ```
   <repository>
       <id>alfresco</id>
       <name>Alfresco</name>
       <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
   </repository>
   <repository>
       <id>mulesoft</id>
       <name>Mulesoft</name>
       <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
   </repository>
   ```

Is it possible to handle the build issues without declaring explicit dependency and repositories?

Answer (score 14):

You are not alone with this problem: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/issues/237

The `xml-apis` artifact version used in version 1.0.4.RELEASE is actually wrong, like you mentioned version `1.4.01` is the correct one.

As long as the versions used in the other two remaining libraries are not uploaded to the public maven repository I am afraid we are stuck using third party repositories.

Note: I would recommend using the Shibbolet repository to get the `2.6.6` version of OpenSaml : https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUsrManJavaInstall

```
        <repository>
            <id>Shibbolet</id>
            <name>Shibbolet</name>
            <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
```

I wonder if all this is the reason that version `1.0.3.RELEASE` is still marked as the current release and version `1.0.4.RELEASE` is marked as snapshot (https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) although they made a blog post about the release of version `1.0.4.RELEASE`  : https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/spring-security-saml-1-0-4-released .... No answer so far: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/issues/242

Note that when using version `1.0.3.RELEASE` there are no problems with the maven dependencies when using maven central.

Comment: This fix did not help me

Comment: I seem to be getting a similar error for 1.0.9 version of the saml extension but adding the new repo suggested here still helped resolve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Adding repo works as well with SAML 1.0.10.RELEASE version.